# Is There Any Way to Determine Which Entities are Being Edited in Entity Framework 6.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Context: converting a project that used EF 6.0 (.Net 4.7.2) to .Net Core 3.

I have upgraded the EF project to version 6.3 and am no longer using a WCF service.  Instead the `.edmx` is being used directly. In the older project, I was able to track changes, and perform some other useful operations, using `dbContext.Entities`.

Is there a similar method for getting a collection of modified, added, or deleted entities using this new setup?

I should note that I am not using EF Core because of difficulties keeping the `.edmx` up to date; we're using database first.

Comment: As a note, using a DB first approach is still possible .net core using scaffolding. You can manage your DB separately, just as you currently do and then generate your code-first context. You would not have an EDMX, just code, but this is a benefit.

Comment: No EDMX?  How would you use a dbContext?  hmmm - have to look into this.  You have a link to any examples (I'll look for one - just checking)?

Comment: You can use the [EF Change Tracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), and [here is a post](https://entityframework.net/change-tracker) on how to use it. HTH.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks jcruz.  This let's me continue without making too many changes to existing code.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to [jcruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169688/jcruz).  In a WCF/OData service setup, I made use of dbContext.Entities to apply global settings to modified data using this technique:

```
foreach (EntityDescriptor entity in context.Entities)
{
    UpdateEntity(entity, userId);
}
```

Switching to .Net Core, the ability to WCF/Odata services is no longer available (I don't think).  Working with the EDMX directly, the code changes only slightly.  Now we use dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries():

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
{
    UpdateEntry(entry, userId);
}
```

Instead of an EntityDescriptor, we pass in a DbEntityEntry object.  Other than that, UpdateEntity() is an exact copy of UpdateEntry().

Comment: To make processing more efficient, you can add a filter to the Entries() method.  Like this:  
.Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)